# Swagger UI with SailsJS v0.12.13

Tags: sails.js, swagger-ui

I'm having the following errors when rendering swagger-ui :

[image]

I've copied the contents of the dist folder from [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) under assets/docs but can't get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there's an [open issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2788) for this error. The UI project is being stabilized (getting to v3) and might be broken now.

If you don't need the very latest version, perhaps you're better off using an [earlier and stable release](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/v2.2.10) of Swagger-UI.

---

*Update*: The issue is now closed and the problem should be resolved.